# How can I get Safari (latest version) to select a default audio track in an MP4 video when there are multiple language tracks embeded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, html5-video, mp4

I have an MP4 file with multiple language audio tracks embedded in the file. Safari (latest version) on the MAC plays all the audio tracks at once. How can I select a default or specific track to play when the video loads in an HTML5 video tag?

Comment: Please enter more information, that is what code you have tried so far and html and javascript code applicable.

Comment: Here is a link to the page in question: http://bigthinkproductions.com/vod8/video_player.html The only active video links are the first two in the left hand menu. those are the ones I've been testing with. the video in question has three audio tracks embedded and they all play at once in Safari. @ArathiSreekumar

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had a JavaScript error that went unchecked and it was causing shenanigans with the video tag. Once I corrected the error I only got the default audio track in the video.